# Postgresql Query Returns No Data

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to migrate my sqlite database to postgresql.
I'm new to postgresql but stuck on this simple issue.

I fist used the pgloader tool to migrate to postgresql and have a working database. I see it created the table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE "AOrder"
(
  "OrderNumber" bigserial NOT NULL,
  "BuyerName" text,
  etc
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "AOrder"
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Using pgadmin3 if I run the SQL query:

```
select
    *
from AOrder
```

This returns the column names plus all the data as expected.

However, the following:

```
select
    *
from "AOrder"
```

This returns just the column names and no data. Where's the data?

So it's not a problem with capitalization. Is there a setting in postgresql that is making this happen?

(This is ultimately the root problem for me since I am then using Sqlachemy which inserts the double quotes in queries. I could not figure out a way to change that behavior.)

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have one table name `aorder` and one table name `"AOrder"` - you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. Details about identifiers and their usage are explained in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: @bschwagg only this should work `select * from "AOrder"`not the other one

Comment: @AndyK That solved it. When I ran my code sqlalchemy was creating duplicate tables that were capitalized!        Sqlalchemy states: "Names which contain no upper case characters will be treated as case insensitive names, and will not be quoted unless they are a reserved word or contain special characters. "  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.params.name